# Setting up Laravel filters on routes to prevent certain users from accessing certain pages

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 different users(normal, technician, administrator)- Each of those users has a different page they can access, but i dont want the normal users to access the tech/admin page and vice versa..  Currently if I log into either of those three users they can all access the normal users page simply by hard coding in the url(/users/home).

```
**ROUTES**
    Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
    Route::get('/user/create', 'UserController@create');
    Route::post('/user/store', 'UserController@store');
    Route::post('/user/login', 'SessionsController@login');

    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
    {
    Route::get('/user/home' , 'UserController@userHome');
    Route::get('/tech/home', 'TechController@techHome');
    Route::get('/admin/home', 'AdminController@adminHome');
    });


**--UserController--**

 public function userHome(){

        $user = Auth::user();
        $username = $user->username;

        return "You have reached the main page for the normal user" . $username;
    }
```

**--SESSIONSCONTROLLER--**

```
public function login() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
        }
        $input = Input::all();
        $attempt = Auth::attempt([

                    'username' => $input['username'],
                    'password' => $input['password']
        ]);

        if ($attempt) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $username = $user->username;
            $accountType = $user->account_type_id;
            if ($accountType == 1) {
                return View::make('normaluser')->with('username', $username);
            } elseif ($accountType == 2) {
                return View::make('technician')->with('username', $username);
            } elseif ($accountType == 3) {
                return View::make('administrator')->with('username', $username);
            }
        } else {
            return "Failed!";
        }
    }
```

Account Types 1=normal, 2=tech, 3=admin

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/user/home' , array('before' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UserController@userHome'));
    Route::get('/tech/home', array('before' => 'tech', 'uses' => 'TechController@techHome'));
    Route::get('/admin/home', array('before' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@adminHome'));
});

Route::filter('tech',function(){
    if(!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->account_type_id != 2){
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Do that also for the other 2 roles! Alternatively you can use the this:

```
Route::when('tech/*','tech');
```

With that approach you don't have to specify the before statement each time.